# Puzzling NDSolve[] behavior for PDE (smooth solution, inconsistent with boundary conditions)

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Consider the following:

```
NDSolve[{D[z[x, y], x, x] + D[z[x, y], y, y] == 0, z[x, 0] == Sin[x], 
  z[0, y] == Cos[y]}, z[x, y], x, y]
```

> {{z[x, y] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}, <>][x, y]}}

This is just everyone's favorite Laplace's equation, but notice that the two side conditions produce a discontinuity in the neighborhood of the origin (strictly speaking, they are not consistent, but we can remove the origin).

However,

```
Plot3D[z[x, y] /. %, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

> [image]

Produces what looks like a perfectly smooth function. Which can't be, since there is a singularity at the origin.

Comment: @paw Thanks for fixing this!

Comment: I can't verify this behaviour since at the moment I have at hand only _Mathematica 9_  which says `NDSolve::ivone: Boundary values may only be specified for one independent variable. Initial values may only be specified at one value of the other independent variable. >>`. I guess you should make it clear what is your problem, perhaps mentioning what happened in earlier versions. It seems neither _ver.9_ nor _ver. 10_ work properly.

Comment: @Artes I thought I WAS being clear: the solution plotted is clearly wrong, since there is no discontinuity (although one is forced by the initial conditions).

Comment: I find it now clearer although at first I wasn't sure what the problem was. It seems other readers were not either since the only upvote is mine. As I guess these inconsistent boundary conditions appear misleading for users only in _ver.10_ while earlier versions don't provide results. It's bettter than being satisfied with the wrong result.

Comment: @Artes fair point, I tried to make the problem clearer.

Comment: im puzzled how NDsolve knows its domain here, what if you specify the domain, what if you put the inconsistant point on the boundary?

Comment: @george2079 I was (and remain) puzzled by this also.

Comment: @george2079, unfortunately, I do not quite understand what you mean. What result would you expect. I'd like to mention a few points. 1) In the case no bounds are given to NDSolve default values are used (-1,1) 2) The boundary conditions are inconsistent at (0,0) - one can not expect a correct solution. 3) In the FEM the PDE is satisfied in a weak sense. Some of the derivation can be found in the [tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html)

Comment: puzzled because the *apparent* default is not documented (that I can find), and I'd expect the inconsistent conditions to generate a warning.  I expect if you did a quarter model so that the conditions are on the region boundary you would get a warning or an error. (I don't have 10 to try it though)